# Plotting multiple lines

Tags: r, plot, line

The following code give me a line graph but only shows the lines of Th1, Th2 and Th17. The other 3 values have significantly lower numbers (max of around 30) yet they should still be visible as lines. What do I need to enter in my code to fix it?

[image: line graph]

```
{
  plot(type="l", termCountTh1, col="green", xaxt = "n", xlab='date', ylab='mentions', 
   main='The amount of articles mentioning when searching CD4+')
   axis(1, at=1:5, labels=2012:2016) 
   lines(termCountTh9, col="deepskyblue4")
   lines(termCountTFH, col="deeppink3")
   lines(termCountiTreg, col="darkred")
   lines(termCountTh17, col="blue")
   lines(termCountTh2, col="purple")
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so others can read it.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ylim=c(ymin, ymax))` in `plot()`. When adding lines with `lines()`, the axes ranges do not get updated. They refer to the values supplied to the initial plot.

Look here for examples: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html